# Upserting a record using ExternalID is giving an error

Tags: externalid

I have an object of type `Contact` with an External ID field called `my_external_id_field`

when i call:
`https://instance/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/my_external_id_field/012443`

with a `patch` method (if i use `post` it complains it's not allowed) with a `.json` file, i get the error:

`` "The my_external_id_field field should not be specified in the sobject data"`, "errorCode:INVALID_FIELD" ``

What could be the reason?

I just want SF to check if a record with this `id` of `012443` exists. If so, update it with the sent `.json`, if not - create it with the sent `.json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not put the external ID field/value in the JSON; it is specified by the URL you're hitting. Simply remove that bit from your file and it should work.

Here's an example using Accounts:

```
PATCH /services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Account/External_Id__c/12345
...

{ "Name": "Test Account A", "Industry": "Technology" }
```

When this transaction completes, External_Id__c will be set to 12345.

---

[image: External ID Upsert In Developer Workbench]

Comment: Thanks, appreciate all of your help today and yesterday!