Getting field should not be specified in data error
I am trying to upsert some data from gcp into Salesforce and getting the below error:

The Loan_Facility_Config_Id__c field should not be specified in the
sobject data.

Loan_Facility_Config_Id__c is an external Id field and unique, and it is a text field, not auto-number or some other readonly fields. Why am I getting this error?
Also checked the permission set, seems the integration user has sufficient access to edit that field.

Does this answer your question?  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205004/upserting-a-record-using-externalid-is-giving-an-error

Can you please share the rest api url and request body payload?
